# Angular GoogleMaps error when using it in test

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using the Angular Material google maps component for integrating Maps in to an Ionic/Capacitor application.

https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps

The map functionality works perfectly fine when I'm developing the application. When I try to run the test file for the component that implements the Google Map, I get this error:

```
Failed: Namespace google not found, cannot construct embedded google map. Please install the Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API
Error: Namespace google not found, cannot construct embedded google map. Please install the Google Maps JavaScript API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API
    at new GoogleMap (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/google-maps/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/google-maps.js:202:1)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.GoogleMap_Factory [as factory] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/google-maps/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/google-maps.js:441:49)
    at getNodeInjectable (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:4029:1)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7964:1)
    at createDirectivesInstances (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7330:1)
    at ɵɵelementStart (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:13902:1)
    at HomePage_Template (ng:///HomePage.js:79:9)
    at executeTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7303:1)
    at renderView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:7112:1)
    at renderComponent (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.js:8373:1)
```

karma.conf.js (this was kinda a last ditch effort, no luck tho.):

```
config.set({
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    require('@angular/google-maps')
  ],
  ...
});
```

HTML:

```
<google-map>
    <map-rectangle
      *ngIf="showSelectionUI"
      [bounds]="bounds"
      [options]="options"
    ></map-rectangle>
    <map-marker
      #marker="mapMarker"
      *ngFor="let position of markerPositions"
      [position]="position"
     ></map-marker>
</google-map>
```

Typescript:

```
@ViewChild(GoogleMap) map: GoogleMap;

@ViewChild(MapRectangle) rectangle: MapRectangle;
```

And here's the entire spec file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { GoogleMapsModule, GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';

describe('HomePage', () => {
  let component: HomePage;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HomePage>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomePage],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        GoogleMapsModule,
        GooglePlaceModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: Storage,
          useValue: {
            get: () => 'manual'
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when developing my library.
Solution was to download the JavaScript API file from Google, save it into the workspace, then configure karma to load it before running the tests.

Take a look at my [`karma.conf` file](https://github.com/BeSpunky/angular-google-maps/blob/18d0b06e31a1e58720e3b0988a4380e92637da50/projects/bespunky/angular-google-maps/karma.conf.js#L37).

And here is the [`google-maps-api.js` file](https://github.com/BeSpunky/angular-google-maps/blob/18d0b06e31a1e58720e3b0988a4380e92637da50/projects/bespunky/angular-google-maps/testing/google-maps-api.js)

> ❕ Note that this means you might have to manually redownload and replace the file if Google releases any breaking changes. Probably not a big deal. Just something to keep in mind.

> Another side note, have a look at my library `@bespunky/angular-google-maps`. In addition to the great features it offers, it also has a testing suite.

Cheers

Comment: Could you direct me to a project and the actual unit test where you're doing this?  I'm having the same issue here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72842732/how-do-i-inject-googleplacemodule-into-jasmine-unit-test

Comment: @shy agam how did you fix the need for the google maps api key?

Comment: Google Maps works without an API key. It just enters a limited development mode. For testing purposes I found it to be insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

I can at least show you how I do this using [Angular Google Maps](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/index.html).  I have an archived repository and website that used to use a Google map with a marker on it [here](https://github.com/xinthose/faithbaptistchurchleland/blob/da56ed732e4020fb78be3912e4cc822deff8914b/src/app/services/services.component.html#L51).

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
```

**HTML Template of component**

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [zoom]="zoom" [longitude]="lng" [mapTypeId]="'hybrid'" style="height: 600px;">
    <agm-marker  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" ></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

**Typescript Template of component**

```
lat: number = 41.6600203;
lng: number = -88.7526228;
zoom: number = 15;
```

Comment: So, the implementation of the map is fine. It’s only the test file where I get this error. I’m open to switching frameworks,but I’ve already moved from Cordova maps to angular/components google maps. So I’m hesitant to go through that process again if I’m missing one small thing for test setup.

Comment: I recently move from agm/core to the native angular implementation of Google Maps, mainly because agm/core is not supported in Angular 10 and above.'
I'm facing the same namespace issue, only in the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after several days of being stuck on it, I decided that my unit test should not care about the map component itself so I mocked GoogleMap, MapInfoWinfow and MapMarker using ng-mocks.

In a way, that solved it for me.

Comment: Mind sharing how?