# How do I inject GooglePlaceModule into Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, google-places-api

I'm trying to write a unit test for a component that uses the GooglePlaceModule.  I keep getting a failed test with the following error:

```js
Failed: Google maps library can not be found
```

I've tried 2 things online while searching for resolutions:

I added this line in the karma.conf.js file per the suggestion:

```
files: [
  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key>=places&language=enhttps://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=<removed>&libraries=places'
],
```

That didn't work.

Here's my spec file:

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { ProfileFormComponent } from './profile-form.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { GooglePlaceModule } from 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete';

describe('ProfileFormComponent', () => {
  let component: ProfileFormComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileFormComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ProfileFormComponent ],
      imports: [IonicModule.forRoot(), ReactiveFormsModule, GooglePlaceModule]
    }).compileComponents();

    window['google'] = {
      maps: {
        Maps: () => {}
      }
    };
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It's pretty basic so far, I'm just trying to get the minimal to pass.

Comment: Hi @D.Hodges, I'm in a similar situation as you are. Were you able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and mock file from some other frustrated programmers about this issue. No api key needed for testing.

I added
imports: [GoogleMapsModule]
to my spec.

And the gmaps.mock.api.js from [here](https://github.com/prasathmani/google-maps-mock-api/blob/master/gmaps.mock.api.js). Added it to the directory src/app/pages/address-form/mock/

To use the gmaps.mock.api.js file in my test I added to the karma.conf.js

```
 files: ['src/app/pages/address-form/mock/google-maps-api.js']
```